# Why Black Screen on native Android

Tags: android, c, gles

I am trying to "software render" a pixel array to the screen in Android 12, using C and OpenGLES.

Relevant code - where I am expecting a 0xff0000ff (red) or 0xff00ffff (violet) rectangle:

```
GLbitfield *rectangle;
GLbitfield *picture;

void Renderer::render() {
for (int i = 0; i<1024*768; i++)
*(picture + i) = 0xff00ffff;

glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 768, GL_RGB_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, picture);
// necessary IDK
glBlitFramebuffer( 0, 0, 1024, 768,0, 0, 1024, 768, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);

eglSwapBuffers( display_, surface_ );
}

GLuint texid;
void Renderer::initRenderer() {

rectangle = (GLbitfield*)malloc(1024 * 768 * sizeof(GLbitfield));
picture = (GLbitfield*)malloc(1024 * 768 * sizeof(GLbitfield));

for( int i=0; i<1024*768; i++ )
*(rectangle + i ) = 0xff0000ff;

glGenTextures(1, &texid);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, rectangle);
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid, 0 );

[...]
}
```

so yeah this compiles and runs with a black screen. I just want GL to "let me through" with my red/purple pixels so that I can change the array *picture later in my render-loop to sth cool.

Or is it kinda totally wrong or even unfeasible? Performance-wise that ARM in the phone should be more than capable to do some software trickery, IMHO..

btw, I really thank Khronos for *removing* glWritePixels() from GLES as this would have seemed to be the ideal solution to me. No need for some stupid texture workaround!

Thanks in advance for your expertise.

Comment: I don't think glFramebufferTexture2D does anything unless you create a framebuffer and bind it. Framebuffers are how you render *to* textures, not from them.